# BigQuery child jobs getting INTERACTIVE priority even when the parent job is BATCH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

When a query job is executed from bq command line tool with --batch option, if it is a single statement, it gets a BATCH priority. But if it is a set of statements, the parent SCRIPT job is assigned BATCH but individual statements are assigned INTERACTIVE priority. Same thing with a CALL to a stored procedure.
The priorities were observed from the information_schema.jobs view. The same behavior happens from Python API as well.

When a parent script job runs with BATCH priority, shouldn't the child jobs get BATCH priority as well? I did not find anything in the documentation that explains this. Maybe there is a reason for this.

**Steps to reproduce:**
*bq query --batch --use_legacy_sql=False "select current_timestamp();"*
-- This produces one entry in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS: QUERY/SELECT/BATCH

*bq query --batch  --use_legacy_sql=False  "select current_timestamp();select current_timestamp();"*
-- This produces 3 entries, the parent SCRIPT jobs is assigned batch, but the two child select jobs get INTERACTIVE. (see image)

[image]

Note: the behavior without the --batch flag, all three entries in JOBS is INTERACTIVE:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get `INTERACTIVE` job priority even if your query is scheduled as `BATCH` priority. If the query has not started or queued within 24 hours, it will change to interactive priority which makes your query to be executed as soon as possible. [BATCH and INTERACTIVE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries) queries use the same resources.

You can go to this [link](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#QueryPriority) for reference.

Comment: Thanks, but the examples I provided were executed instantaneously. I understand now that BigQuery can alter the priority, but would love to know the rules for it. When a user requests a batch priority and it gets assigned interactive, it can have an adverse impact - because there is a hard limit on how many interactive queries can run simultaneously.